# Textsuperscript does not work with letters

Tags: superscripts

An attempt to write 8th

`8\textsuperscript{th}` resulted in the same text 8th

while the same environment worked well with numbers

`8\textsuperscript{8}` and produced correct view with subscript.

Why does textsuperscript not work with letters?
P.S. Math mode is not used due to inattractive font view

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage,oneside,openany,a5paper]{book} 
\usepackage{geometry}  
\geometry{a5paper}
\begin{document}
8\textsuperscript{th}
\\
8\textsuperscript{1}
\end{document}
```

[image: letters were ignored, while numbers are not]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I prefix the instructions `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` and append the instruction `\end{document}` to your macros and compile the resulting file under pdflatex, I do *not* get the problem you state you're getting. Something else must be going on that you haven't told us about. Please help us out by posting an MWE that generates the problem.

Comment: Please specify your documentclass and preamble in order to reproduce your issue. I have seen that behalf of X∃TeX you would need the package [`xltxtra`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/xltxtra/).

Comment: The minimal example shows superscript “th”. On the other hand, superscripting “th” is not considered good style: it's a Victorian age usage resurrected in recent times by a well known word processing piece of software.

Comment: I got the same error using a ttf font. As I suppose from the style of your "8th", you probably did a similar thing? `\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Calibri.ttf}`

Answer (score 7):

Please always post complete documents that show the problem. It should work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

8\textsuperscript{th} 8th

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour can arise from you using the `realscripts` package and a font missing the superscript characters.

You might try either to remove the `\usepackage{realscripts}` or to redefine `\textsuperscript`

```
\renewcommand{\textsuperscript}[1]{\fakesuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand{\textsubscript}[1]{\fakesubscript{#1}}
```

Another possibility of actually replacing only the missing characters has been discussed in this thread, but (in my opinion) is not worth the efford: [realscripts – can fakescripts substitute single missing chars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495609/realscripts-can-fakescripts-substitute-single-missing-chars)