# realscripts – can fakescripts substitute single missing chars

Tags: luatex, fontspec, superscripts, opentype, directlua

I have a font with real OT-superscripts which I can use easily with the `realscripts`-package. But I also need a superscript decimal dot which doesn't exist, thus `realscripts` falls back to the regular form. This is the expected behaviour but I'd like to automatically substitute the `\fakesuperscript{.}` whereever `\textsuperscript{.}` occurs.

I tried a crude hack where I declare an arbitrary unicode char to be "period.superscript" and try to let Lua add it to the font-features. Both parts work on their own but not in combination; I suspect that the lua instruction is processed before the `\newunicodechar`, isn't it?

Is there a way to make my hack work by somehow changing the order of the processes?

Or is there any other way to make `\fakesuperscript`s be used as stand-ins for missing real superscripts? It doesn't matter for me whether all are replaced or whether I'd have to define them one by one. Either solution would be fine.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}


\usepackage{realscripts}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{}{\fakesuperscript{.}}

\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "sups",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
      period = "",
      ["period.onum"] = "",
      Q = "Ɋ",
      ["Q.onum"] = "Ɋ",
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}

I can use the defined char directly: o\textsuperscript{1}\textsuperscript{5}o

But not, as I hoped, via the superscript-command: o\textsuperscript{1.5}o

The \textsuperscript{Question} whether the Lua part works is obviously answerd by yes.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\newunicodechar{}{\fakesuperscript{.}}` defines a command (an active char). This command is processed before any font related stuff is done. In `period = "",` the `` is not a command, it is a glyph. It will not expand to `\fakesuperscript`.

Imho the easiest would be to replace problematic symbols (this could also be done with lua, I'm using expl3-regex here):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{realscripts}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mysuperscript{m}
{
  \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {\.}{\c{fakesuperscript}\cB\{\.\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {\Q}{\c{fakesuperscript}\cB\{\Q\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl
  \textsuperscript{\l_tmpa_tl}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

o\mysuperscript{1.5}
o\mysuperscript{Question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the "1" really bold and the "5" lightface, or do I need new glasses?

Comment: @barbarabeeton it looks a bit like this, but it is not a problem of my code, with \textsuperscript you get the same, it must be the font.