# missing superscript glyph

Tags: symbols, superscripts, missing

I am using XeLaTeX TeXLive on Debian and Minion Pro for typesetting a commentary with many footnote series (with bigfoot). Minion Pro lacks "c" superscript, so `realscript` replaces it with normal c. Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{H}[alph] % huettenexemplar

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\FN@allmarks}{266}{256}{}{}
\makeatother

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common,Required}]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
Das Seiende\footnoteH{ja ‚ich‘}, dessen\footnoteH{Aber}
Analyse\footnoteH{Welches?} zur Aufgabe\footnoteH{daß es}\\
\end{document}
```

[image: note without superscript]

I manually fixed the problem (that also happens with "f" and other letters):

```
\begin{document}
Das Seiende\footnoteH{ja ‚ich‘}, dessen\footnoteH{Aber}
Analyse\textsuperscript*{c}\footnotetextH[3]{Welches?} zur
Aufgabe\footnoteH[4]{daß es}
\end{document}
```

[image: fixed]

One possibility is not to use `xltxtra`, but I wish to use the typographic superscripts instead of the scaled ones for the other letters. Any help is really appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495609 ?

Comment: Thanks, @Thérèse, I will try with that.

Comment: xlxtra is not recommended these days also never use [T1]{fontenc} with xelatex (all hyphenation will be wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a reason why MinionPro does not cover all Latin letters in the `sups` feature.

Example, based on yours with some differences:

1. instead of `xltxtra` I just load `realscripts` (avoid the former)
2. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should not be used with (Xe|Lua)LaTeX
3. `classicthesis` is nowadays mostly incompatible with `scrbook`
4. `Ligatures=TeX` is predefined
5. `Ligatures=Common` is on by default
6. `Ligatures=Required` is not supported by MinionPro
7. `\setlength{\textheight}{3cm}` is just for making a smaller picture

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters

\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{H}[alph] % huettenexemplar

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\FN@allmarks}{266}{256}{}{}
\makeatother

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}

\setlength{\textheight}{3cm}

\begin{document}

Ligatures: ``fi ff fl''

Das Seiende\footnoteH{ja ‚ich‘}, dessen\footnoteH{Aber}
Analyse\footnoteH{Welches?} zur Aufgabe\footnoteH{daß es}

\bigskip

Superscript letters: {\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, MinionPro (at least in the version I have, from Adobe Acrobat Reader) lacks several letters respecting the `sups` feature called by `VerticalPosition=Superior` (which is the same as the `realscripts` package does).

The documentation of `realscripts` warns about the problem and it seems that other Adobe fonts lack the superscripts

[image]

You can see that the problem is exactly the same as with MinionPro.

What can you do? Nothing, actually, except fixing faulty footnote markers by hand, if you want to keep `realscripts`.  You can consider using a font that has the required glyph variants.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters

\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{H}[alph] % huettenexemplar

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\FN@allmarks}{266}{256}{}{}
\makeatother

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Libertinus Serif}

\textheight=3cm

\begin{document}

Ligatures: ``fi ff fl''

Das Seiende\footnoteH{ja ‚ich‘}, dessen\footnoteH{Aber}
Analyse\footnoteH{Welches?} zur Aufgabe\footnoteH{daß es}

\bigskip

Superscript letters: {\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is an example of “fixing by hand”:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters

\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % 
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{H}[alph] % huettenexemplar

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\FN@allmarks}{266}{256}{}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\@makefnmark}{}
 {
  \mbox{\footnotemarkfont \__dsv_textsuperscript:e {\@thefnmark }}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__dsv_textsuperscript:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {c}{\fakesuperscript{c}}
    {f}{\fakesuperscript{f}}
    {j}{\fakesuperscript{j}}
    {k}{\fakesuperscript{k}}
    {p}{\fakesuperscript{p}}
    {q}{\fakesuperscript{q}}
    {u}{\fakesuperscript{u}}
    {v}{\fakesuperscript{v}}
    {w}{\fakesuperscript{w}}
    {x}{\fakesuperscript{x}}
    {y}{\fakesuperscript{y}}
    {z}{\fakesuperscript{z}}
   }
   {\realsuperscript{#1}}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__dsv_textsuperscript:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}

\setlength{\textheight}{3cm}

\begin{document}

Ligatures: ``fi ff fl''

Das Seiende\footnoteH{ja ‚ich‘}, dessen\footnoteH{Aber}
Analyse\footnoteH{Welches?} zur Aufgabe\footnoteH{daß es}

\bigskip

Superscript letters: {\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg for the solution and commentaries regarding the package usage. Yes, Minion Pro, and other Adobe Fonts, do not provide these glyphs, so I was looking for a `fakesuperscript` solution like yours. Other fonts like Garamond Premier Pro provides all latin letters and numbers in superscript form, but I prefer the more 'beefy' Minion Pro.  Thanks